# Python3 add colour to specific outputted words from lists in a sentence

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, colors

My below code is currently checking a text file to see if it can find words in a sentence from my lexicon file, if it does find one it then searches this line to see if it can find a word from a secondary list if both of these conditions are met in a line then this line is printed.

What i am trying to do is set the lexicon word colour to for example red & blue for the words found in the secondary list that is called CategoryGA, my purpose for this is to easily identify in the printout there each of the found words have came from.

```
import re
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
import sys

from Categories.GainingAccess import GA

Chatpath = "########/Chat1.txt"
Chatfile = Chatpath

lpath = 'Lexicons/######.txt'
lfile = lpath
CategoryGA = GA
Hits = []

"""
text_file = open(path, "r")

lines = text_file.read().split()

c = Counter(lines)

for i, j in c.most_common(50):
    print(i, j)

"""


# class LanguageModelling:

def readfile():
    Word_Hit = None
    with open(Chatfile) as file_read:
        content = file_read.readlines()
        for line_num, line in enumerate(content):
            if any(word in line for word in CategoryGA):
                Word_Hit = False
                for word in CategoryGA:
                    if line.find(word) != -1:
                        Word_Hit = True
                        Hits.append(word)
                        Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)

                        print('%s appeared on Line %d : %s' % (word, line_num, Cleanse))

        file_read.close()

    count = Counter(Hits)
    count.keys()
    for key, value in count.items():
        print(key, ':', value)


def readlex():
    with open(lfile) as l_read:
        l_content = l_read.readlines()
        for line in l_content:
            r = re.compile(r'^\d+\s+\d+\.\d+%\s*')
            l_Cleanse = r.sub('', line)
            print(l_Cleanse)

    l_read.close()


def LanguageDetect():
    with open(Chatfile) as c_read, open(lfile) as l_read:
        c_content = c_read.readlines()

        lex_content = l_read.readlines()
        for line in c_content:
            Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)
            if any(lex_word in line for lex_word in lex_content) \
                    and \
                    any(cat_word in line for cat_word in CategoryGA):
                lex_word = '\033[1;31m{}\033[1;m'.format(lex_word)

                cat_word = '\033[1;44m{}\033[1;m'.format(cat_word)
                print(Cleanse)
                # print(cat_word)

    c_read.close()
    l_read.close()

#readfile()
LanguageDetect()
# readlex()
```

This is my full code but the issue is occurring in the "LanguageDetect" method my current way of trying by assigning the lex_word & cat_word variables hasn't worked and frankly I'm stumped as to what to try next.

Lexicon:

```
31547   4.7072% i
25109   3.7466% u
20275   3.0253% you
10992   1.6401% me
9490    1.4160% do
7681    1.1461% like
6293    0.9390% want
6225    0.9288% my
5459    0.8145% have
5141    0.7671% your
5103    0.7614% lol
4857    0.7247% can
```

then within the readlex method i use:

```
r = re.compile(r'^\d+\s+\d+\.\d+%\s*')
            l_Cleanse = r.sub('', line)
```

to remove everything before the word/character i believe this may be the main issue as to why i can't colour the lexicon word but unsure on how to fix this.

Comment: Color interpretation depends on the terminal you are running. Are you sure your terminal can handle colors ?

Comment: I'm just outputting via pycharm currently so that should is able to handle colours, i believe currently the issues lies more with the code than the terminal

Comment: `lex_word = ''\033[1;31m' + lex_word + '\033[1;m'` works for me thus why I asked

Comment: Where in the code did you use this?

Comment: I extracted it, could not test your code due to lacking libraries, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem comes from the way you handle the line data but maybe i did not understand your question clearly.

That should do the trick :

```
lex_content = ['aaa', 'xxx']
CategoryGA = ['ccc', 'ddd']
line = 'abc aaa bbb ccc'

for lex_word in lex_content:
  for cat_word in CategoryGA:
    if lex_word in line and cat_word in line:
      print(lex_word, cat_word)
      line = line.replace(lex_word, '\033[1;31m' + lex_word + '\033[1;m')
      line = line.replace(cat_word, '\033[1;44m' + cat_word + '\033[1;m')
      print(line)
```

Gives the output:

[image: output]

Comment: so I've added this in and the cat_word works but lex_word does not i think one reason of why it isn't working is the way the lexicon looks but i do cleanse the data with a regex statement in the readlex method i will update my question with how my lexicon is displayed before and after regex code